# Express js does not return data after success to Ajax call

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

I am trying to store the data from client end javascript to server end express js after storing returning some data. I can receive the data at express API `userdetail` function but unable to return to ajax. Please can I get help?

```
 $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:8080/api/save_user/",
                type: "POST",
                crossDomain: true,
                data: { name: 'Justin', number: '662***' },
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (response) {
                    var resp = JSON.parse(response)

                },
                error: function (xhr, status) {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
```

> Express Js server side

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path')
const os = require('os');
const app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post('/api/save_user', (req, res) => {
   Usermodel.saveData(req.body.name,req.body.number)
        .then(function (userdetail) {
            res.send({ success: true, data: userdetail });
        })
        .catch(next);
})
```

Comment: you dont need to parse the JSON returned by server. just do console.log(response) in your ajax success to check the response returned.

Comment: I would hope you do some integrity checks for the name and number passed in before just blindly sending whatever the client sends into your database.

Comment: thanks for replay, i solved it, i need to add return to express api function ```return Usermodel.saveData(req.body.name,req.body.number) ```